# With visualizer date information : application/pdf; base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, reader

I have the base64 to a pdf file and wish to see this base64 in javascript.

Comment: `console.log(myBase64EncodedString)`.

Comment: can u please elaborate?

Comment: .view 8 windows application